# D3 output not rendering in Safari, Firefox, Edge and IE. Works in Chrome

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have an application that outputs data from D3. The output looks like this:

```html
<div class="horizontalBarGraphContainer"><h4 class="crux-component-title">Greatest Rocker</h4><div class="ct HorizontalBarContainer"><div class="ct HorizontalBarGraph"><div style="width: 100%; height: 410px; position: relative;"><svg width="988" height="410"><g style="transform: translateY(0px);"><rect width="708" y="0" x="240" height="45" fill="#4dbf9d">Tiny Tim</rect><foreignObject fill="#000" width="205" x="0" y="0" class="crux-label-style foreignObject" text-anchor="start">Tiny Tim</foreignObject><text class="ct count crux-numbers crux-numbers--medium" fill="#000" dy=".35em" dx="10" y="22.5" text-anchor="start" x="948">26</text><text class="ct user-answer crux-label-style crux-label-style--small" fill="#000" dx="948" dy="55" text-anchor="end"></text></g><g style="transform: translateY(80px);"><rect width="626.3076923076923" y="0" x="240" height="45" fill="#4dbf9d">Elvis</rect><foreignObject fill="#000" width="205" x="0" y="0" class="crux-label-style foreignObject" text-anchor="start">Elvis</foreignObject><text class="ct count crux-numbers crux-numbers--medium" fill="#000" dy=".35em" dx="10" y="22.5" text-anchor="start" x="866.3076923076923">23</text><text class="ct user-answer crux-label-style crux-label-style--small" fill="#000" dx="866.3076923076923" dy="55" text-anchor="end"></text></g><g style="transform: translateY(160px);"><rect width="544.6153846153846" y="0" x="240" height="45" fill="#4dbf9d">Ted Nugent</rect><foreignObject fill="#000" width="205" x="0" y="0" class="crux-label-style foreignObject" text-anchor="start">Ted Nugent</foreignObject><text class="ct count crux-numbers crux-numbers--medium" fill="#000" dy=".35em" dx="10" y="22.5" text-anchor="start" x="784.6153846153846">20</text><text class="ct user-answer crux-label-style crux-label-style--small" fill="#000" dx="784.6153846153846" dy="55" text-anchor="end"></text></g><g style="transform: translateY(240px);"><rect width="544.6153846153846" y="0" x="240" height="45" fill="#4dbf9d">Iggy Pop</rect><foreignObject fill="#000" width="205" x="0" y="0" class="crux-label-style foreignObject" text-anchor="start">Iggy Pop</foreignObject><text class="ct count crux-numbers crux-numbers--medium" fill="#000" dy=".35em" dx="10" y="22.5" text-anchor="start" x="784.6153846153846">20</text><text class="ct user-answer crux-label-style crux-label-style--small" fill="#000" dx="784.6153846153846" dy="55" text-anchor="end"></text></g><g style="transform: translateY(320px);"><rect width="381.2307692307692" y="0" x="240" height="45" fill="#4dbf9d">Jon Bon Jovi</rect><foreignObject fill="#000" width="205" x="0" y="0" class="crux-label-style foreignObject" text-anchor="start">Jon Bon Jovi</foreignObject><text class="ct count crux-numbers crux-numbers--medium" fill="#000" dy=".35em" dx="10" y="22.5" text-anchor="start" x="621.2307692307693">14</text><text class="ct user-answer crux-label-style crux-label-style--small" fill="#000" dx="621.2307692307693" dy="55" text-anchor="end"></text></g></svg></div></div></div></div>
```

In Chrome, I see both the title (in the rect element). But in Safari, Firefox, Edge and IE I don't. Is there some reason why this only works in Chrome?

Demonstrated and viewable in this Codepen: https://codepen.io/serpicolugnut/pen/xWZwbb

Comment: Could we see the d3 code that produces this?

Comment: @RobertLongson - that was it. The foreignObject element needed a height set to it. Strange that Chrome displays it without but the other browsers do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers implement SVG 1.1 with some smattering of SVG 2. Different browsers have implemented different parts of the SVG 2 specification.

One of the myriad changes in SVG 2 is that [width and height parameters on foreignObject elements are now optional and can be set in CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/changes.html#extend). Chrome is the first browser to implement this part of SVG 2.

Your content is missing a height attribute on the foreignObject elements so it only renders in Chrome at the moment.